# Change a column to not allow nulls

Tags: sql-server, null, alter-column

So I want to change a column in my SQL Server database to not allow nulls, but I keep getting an error. this is the sql statement I am using:

```
alter table [dbo].[mydatabase] alter column WeekInt int not null
```

and this is the error I am getting :

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'WeekInt', table 'CustomerRadar.dbo.tblRWCampaignMessages'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I'm pretty sure my sql is right, and there are no nulls currently in the column I am trying to change so I am really not sure as to what is causing the problem. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: There error seems to indicate you are running an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, not an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: are you 110% sure that there aren't any `nulls` in that column, the error would suggest there are.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no it is definitely a alter script

Comment: @TI just doubled checked and there are a few, cant believe I missed that. Will rectify it and get back to you

Comment: Nothing wrong with that statement.  Definitely a case of rogue NULLs.  Probably why you want to add the constraint.  =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Clearly, the table has `NULL` values in it.  Which you can check with:

```
select *
from mydatabase
where WeekInt is NULL;
```

Then, you can do one of two things.  Either change the values:

```
update mydatabase
    set WeekInt = -1
    where WeekInt is null;
```

Or delete the offending rows:

```
delete from mydatabase
    where WeekInt is null;
```

Then, when all the values are okay, you can do the `alter table` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change a column to not null, and you are getting this error message, yet it appears the column has no nulls, ensure you are checking for `is null` and not `= null` (which gives different results).

```
Select * from ... where column is null
```

instead of

```
Select * from ... where column = null
```

I am adding this because it tripped me up and took a while to resolve.

Comment: That one got me too. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You should send a default value, then it will change all the previous record to -1 in this example.

alter table [dbo].[mydatabase] alter column WeekInt int not null DEFAULT '-1';